# Php, date_modify() with a variable

Tags: php

I need to use the indexed element as the amount to change the date by

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$ids = explode(',',$id);

$dateCreated = date('Y-m-d'); 
$dateExpiredtemp =date_create($dateCreated);
date_modify($dateExpiredtemp,'+ $ids[2]'); 
$dateExpired = date('$dateExpiredtemp');
```

date_modify($dateExpiredtemp,'**+ $ids[2]'**);

This line provides this error

Warning: date_modify(): Failed to parse time string (+ $ids[2]) at position 0 (+): Unexpected character in

$ids[2] is a string and it needs to be carried into the altering parameter of date_modify

Comment: share value for `$id`?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of code

```
date_modify($dateExpiredtemp,'+ $ids[2]');
```

into

```
date_modify($dateExpiredtemp,'+ ' . $ids[2]);
```

Your initial code will not recognize the `$ids[2]` since it is included in the string. Therefore, `$ids[2]` won't be parsed.

Comment: what about this `$dateExpired = date('$dateExpiredtemp');`  ?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something wrong with your `$ids` array.

I assume that `$ids[2]` is just a number and that is why you're getting an error. You need to specify a unit of time such as `days`. Take a look at the code below, I have added `days` to the end of the 2nd parameter in the `date_modify` function.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$ids = explode(',',$id);

$dateCreated = date('Y-m-d'); 
$dateExpiredtemp =date_create($dateCreated);
date_modify($dateExpiredtemp,'+ $ids[2] days'); 
$dateExpired = date('$dateExpiredtemp');
```

Comment: Yes, I know, I explicitly didn’t say integer as I meant that it’s a string containing only a number eg: “1”. I said this because if the string only contains a number then it will result in an error like the OP provided